# Is PayPal's percentage fee applied before or after the flat fee?

Tags: fees, paypal

For example: sending $100 at base US rates (2.9%, $0.30):

Fee is $0.30 + $2.8913 = $3.1913 (applying the % after the flat rate)
Fee is $2.90 + $0.30 = $3.20 (applying the % to the $ sent)

Comment: If you applied the % after the flat rate, you’d have a fee of $0.30 + $2.987 = $3.2087. It would be a higher fee than if the percentage is applied first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to PayPal’s [What are the fees for PayPal accounts?](https://www.paypal.com/jm/selfhelp/article/what-are-the-fees-for-paypal-accounts-faq690) page, the percentage does not include the flat fee:

> The fee in the U.S. is 2.9% plus $0.30 USD of the amount you send. For example, if you send $100.00 USD by credit card, the fee would be $3.20 USD ($2.90 + $0.30).